# Limite de paginas no DOMPDF - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou realizando um requerimento de impressão pro DOMPDF, cuja quantidade é superior a 200 paginas. Quando faço a solicitação ele não consegue gerar, mas se passo uma condição pra gerar até um determinado registro, inferior a essa quantidade, o mesmo é gerado. 
Existe alguma configuração ou algum limite que o dompdf não consegue gerar?
Alguém teve algo parecido?

Minha consulta esta dessa forma:

```
 public function pdf()
  {
    $athletes = Category::join('athletes', 'categories.id', '=', 'category_id')
      ->select(
        'athletes.id',
        'athletes.name',
        'athletes.city',
        'athletes.birthday',
        'athletes.academy',
        'athletes.telephone',
        'athletes.rg',
        'athletes.cpf',
        'athletes.genre',
        'categories.initials',
        'categories.weight',
        'categories.description')
      ->whereBetween('categories.initials',['A1', 'G1']) //(Limite gerado) 
      ->orderBy('categories.initials', 'ASC')
      ->get();

    $html = view('admin.pdf.athletes', compact('athletes'));
    $pdf  = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');

    return $pdf->download('relatorio_atletas_2017.pdf');
  }
```

Atenciosamente.

Comment: Ele retorna algum erro ou somente só não gera ?

Comment: Não retorna nenhum erro, simplesmente carrega uma pagina localhost não atendendo a solicitação.